# Why do I have to escape `]` in my regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I got an error when I ran the following:

```
perl -ne 'print unless (/[A-G][\d|\s|m|#|$]/)' file
```

The error:

```
Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[A-G][ <-- HERE \d|\s|m|#|5.022001/ at -e line 1, <> line 1
```

I resolved the error by escaping the `]` at the end of the line:

```
perl -ne 'print unless (/[A-G][\d|\s|m|#|$\]/)' file
```

Why did I have to escape the last `]`? What prevents the bracket from being matched?

I have noticed this is not the case for all `[]` matches. Is this a special case?

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong here :- It should be `(\d|\s|m|#|$)`..

Comment: @anubhava yeah, that can also be possible..OMG that was too dumb

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks for reminding. I understand where I was wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print unless (/[A-G][\d|\s|m|#|$]/)' file
```

Apparently the `$]` is being interpreted by Perl as the `$]` variable, which contains the current version of Perl.

But that regular expression doesn't make much sense anyway. In this part of it:

```
[\d|\s|m|#|$]
```

the text between the `[` and `]` is a sequence of characters or ranges of characters, and the expression matches any one of those characters. Adding a backslash:

```
[\d|\s|m|#|\$]
```

means it's going to match a single backslash, 'd', 's', m', '$', '|', or '$' character. (I'm not 100% certain about the details.) You probably want:

```
(\d|\s|m|#|$)
```

You can tweak that if you don't want the matching text stored in `$1`:

```
(?:\d|\s|m|#|$)
```

but that's probably not worthwhile for this one-liner.

Also, the outer parentheses aren't necessary.  Putting this all together, what you *probably* want is:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /[A-G](\d|\s|m|#|$)/' file
```

Comment: `$)` is also a variable, but the regex parser is coded to not consider it one.

Comment: `(\d|\s|m|#|$)` assumes `$` should match "end of string". If you want `$` to match `$`, use `[\d\sm#\$]`.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's the `$` that needs to be escaped there, because `$]` is the special variable used for [*The revision, version, and subversion of the Perl interpreter*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: I used `$` to denote the end of line character. If I escape `$` will it still represent the end of line?

Comment: Yes, but if you fix just that one thing the regular expression still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @OneFace In a bracketed character class, `$` means a literal dollar sign.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for the tip! I understand now